# dequeue() in Queue implememtation that uses a circular linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I use a circular linked list to implement a `queue`, and it only holds one `last` (note that `last.next` links to the `first`, not `null`).

```
public class Queue<T> {

    private Node last;
    private int n;

    private class Node {
        T value;
        Node next;
        Node(T t, Node n) {
            value = t;
            next = n;
        }
    }

    public Queue() {
        last = null;
        n = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return n == 0;
    }

    public void enqueue(T item) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            last = new Node(item, null);
            last.next = last;
        } else {
            Node tmp = new Node(item, last.next);
            last.next = tmp;
            last = tmp;
        }
        n++;
    }

   // other code
}
```

I think the correct way of `dequeue()` is :

```
public T dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Node first = last.next;
    T t = first.value;
    if (last == first) {
        last = null;
    } else {
        last.next = first.next;
    }
    n--;
    return t;
}
```

This is because we should set `last` to `null` if there is one element.

However, the alternative way in following also works, why?

```
public T dequeue2() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Node first = last.next;
    T t = first.value;
    last.next = first.next;
    n--;
    return t;
}
```

I call `N` times `dequeue2()` after `N` times `enqueue()`, and `assert queue.last== null`. To my surprize, the assertion passes. I think the `last` can never be `null` if I use `dequeue2()`.
So, is the `dequeue2()` correct?

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation or a review? If the latter, of which codes, all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### dequeue2

This method works because, when there's just one remaining item in the queue, the line:

> ```
> Node first = last.next;
> ```

sets `first` to be the same as `last` (because, for a 1-sized queue `last.next` is a pointer to `last`).

In the other `dequeue()` you set `last` to be null when there's nothing left, but this does not make a difference, really (other than Garbage Collection) because the `enqueue` function checks the empty queue using `n == 0` and not `last == null`

### static inner class

Your `Node` class does not have any need for a back-reference to the `Queue`. It should be a static inner class `private static class Node......`. To do that, though, you need to make it generic too. Use a letter other than `T` to represent the generic class...

```
 private static class Node<U> {
    U value;
    Node<U> next;
    Node(U val, Node<U> n) {
        value = val;
        next = n;
    }
}
```

This saves a small amount of memory, but it is good practice. When you create the Node instances now, the code will change from:

> ```
> private Node last;
> ```

to

```
private Node<T> last;
```

and you will add the `<>` diamond operator here:

```
Node<T> tmp = new Node<>(item, last.next);
```

### Constructor:

Your constructor:

> ```
> public Queue() {
>     last = null;
>     n = 0;
> }
> ```

should just be:

```
public Queue() {
}
```

as you don't need to explicitly supply the default values.

### General

Your code is neat, your variable names are not bad, and the use of generics is good.

As a learning exercise you should spend some time seeing if you can make it implement `java.util.Queue` interface (it's not easy - fair warning) because that will teach you a bit about what the actual Java Collections API offers.

Comment: (+1) Good review. However I feel that explicitly supplying the default values shows the intent of the programmer and might be easier for a non-Java person to read.

Comment: @Astrobleme - that's perhaps true, but then set them on the field declaration, and not again in the constructor